# How to Combine two mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine these two queries with two captain should be equal :

```
select distinct(captain_name),sum(finaldiscount) as tot,payment_mode 
from   order_master 
where  payment_mode='card' 
group  by captain_name

select distinct(captain_name),sum(finaldiscount) as tot,payment_mode 
from   order_master 
where  payment_mode='cash' 
group  by captain_name
```

Comment: why combine the same query?  i dont see the difference between the queries.

Comment: Both queries are looking same

Comment: it has been wrongly edited, there was `payment_mode='card'` in first query.

Answer (score 0):

Combine can be a **JOIN** or an **UNION**

For **JOIN**:

```
Select * 
from
(select distinct(captain_name) capName,sum(finaldiscount) as tot,payment_mode from order_master where payment_mode='card' group by captain_name ) t1
INNER JOIN
(select distinct(captain_name) capName,sum(finaldiscount) as tot,payment_mode from order_master where payment_mode='cash' group by captain_name) t2 on t1.capName = t2.capName
```

For **UNION**:

```
Select * 
    from
    (select distinct(captain_name) capName,sum(finaldiscount) as tot,payment_mode from order_master where payment_mode='card' group by captain_name ) t1
    UNION
    (select distinct(captain_name) capName,sum(finaldiscount) as tot,payment_mode from order_master where payment_mode='cash' group by captain_name) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT captain_name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_mode = 'cash' THEN finaldiscount ELSE 0 END) AS cashTotal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_mode = 'card' THEN finaldiscount ELSE 0 END) AS cardTotal
FROM order_master 
WHERE payment_mode IN ('cash', 'card') 
GROUP BY captain_name
```

**OR**

```
SELECT captain_name, payment_mode, SUM(finaldiscount) total
FROM order_master 
WHERE payment_mode IN ('cash', 'card') 
GROUP BY captain_name, payment_mode
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT captain_name,
       Sum(finaldiscount) AS tot,
       payment_mode
FROM   order_master
WHERE  payment_mode IN( 'cash', 'card' )
       AND captain_name IN (SELECT captain_name
                            FROM   order_master
                            WHERE  payment_mode IN( 'cash', 'card' )
                            GROUP  BY captain_name
                            HAVING Count(DISTINCT payment_mode) = 2)
GROUP  BY captain_name,payment_mode
```

the sub query will return only those `captain_name` which have both `payment_mode` i.e. `card` and `cash`. then select rows of those `captain_name` and `group by` it by `captain_name,payment_mode`.

and if you don't want separate rows for `card` and `cash` then use this :

```
SELECT captain_name,SUM(finaldiscount)
FROM   order_master
WHERE  payment_mode IN( 'cash', 'card' )
GROUP  BY captain_name
HAVING Count(DISTINCT payment_mode) = 2
```

Note : I assumed that `two captain should be equal` means only those captain which are returned by both queries, should be returned by combined query.